# Referencing a div multiple times in Backbone.js view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, refactoring

Was wondering what the best way to handle this would be. Say I have a div that I'm referencing within multiple methods within one of my Backbone views and I don't want to have to keep re-querying it every time.

e.g.

```
Backbone.View.extend({
    showReviewOverlay : function(evt) {
        var $overlay = $('#js-add-review-overlay');
        $(evt.currentTarget).prepend($overlay.show());
    }
    hideReviewOverlay : function(evt) {
        var $overlay = $('#js-add-review-overlay');
        $(evt.currentTarget).closest($overlay.hide());
    }
});
```

Would the preferred method for referencing it be to declare it as an object? Or is there some better pattern that I don't know about?

e.g.

```
Backbone.View.extend({
    overlay : { 'container' : $('#js-add-review-overlay') },

    showReviewOverlay : function(evt) {
        $(evt.currentTarget).prepend(this.container.overlay.show());
    }
    hideReviewOverlay : function(evt) {
        $(evt.currentTarget).closest(this.container.overlay.hide());
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you not want to use `el` for some reason?

Comment: @dbaseman the overlay is just a hidden div template somewhere in the page, and I thought using el was just to use as the div I'd like to capture all events through? Maybe I am missing the point of `el` entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a specific case, you might grab a reference to the element when `render` is called:

```
Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function () {
        // do rendering stuff
        this.$overlay = this.$('#js-add-review-overlay');
    },
    showReviewOverlay : function(evt) {
        $(evt.currentTarget).prepend(this.$overlay.show());
    }
});
```

Comment: why `this.$`? The jQuery object, `$` is gloabl.

Comment: Because `this.$` is safer. It is scoped to the view. It is an alias for something like `$(<selector>, this.el)`.

Comment: Because limiting the scope of the query to the view will save searching the entire document :^)

Comment: Say I have a `render()` method and an `initialize()` method, would I declare this within the initialize or the render?

Comment: `onRender`. The selector will return `[]` before being rendered.